# Can this relation be modeled in RDBMS?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

Considering the following relation

OWL:Class Hotel hasDistanceTo OWL:Class TouristAttraction

Is it possible to model this relationship in relation databases? If so, will that be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  And yes.

Essentially have three tables: hotel,  attraction,  hotelattractiondistance where the third table has two foreign: primary keys: one to hotel and one to attraction with a distance attribute.

Comment: then why should one prefer to use ontologies over relational databases? Is there any scenario, where ontology-based model is superior to relational data model?

Comment: if your data can be modelled using a small number of tables, relational DBs will win. RDF-based model is superior if you have many different types of object and are interested in quering by various relations between these objects. that is where your data is better expressed and queried as an RDF graph rather than tables and relations. there is industry interest in RDF and SPARQL, for example: http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/blogger/2012/03/02/cray-announces-an-rdf-eating-graph-appliance/

Comment: In my experiience, these are usually called "join tables", but Wikipedia as a big list of terms under [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, Associative Entity refers to only an E-R diagram.

Comment: @mattsap Yes, the associative *entity* is not the same as the *table* that represents it.  The point is that having a table that exists just to relate rows from two other names is a well-known pattern, and it's not uncommon.  From the article: "Associative tables are colloquially known under many names, including mapping table, junction table, cross-reference table, bridge table, join table, intermediary table, intersection table, linking table, many-to-many resolver, link table, pairing table, transition table, crosswalk, or association table." Those are what this answer is describing, right?

Comment: Correct! Nice explanation